# What's this option in the AOSPA stock email app?

Tags: stock-email-app

On my Paranoid Android ROM, that I installed because the old CM ROM I was using is dead link and I needed a ROM to run, I am configuring the Email app, but I can't understand what is the meaning of this setting:

[image: picture]
(It's the fourth option of the notifications settings, for non-French speakers)

I have not seen it in any other screenshots, it isn't in the translation files and isn't documented anywhere.

I think it is for having a notification for each email instead than a global "2 new messages" one, but it is only an assumption.

What does this setting mean? How will the modification of this setting will change the behavior of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your assumption is exactly correct.

Google has laid out these settings the same way as they have in Gmail, which has better translations. The bottom one is indeed the per-message notification toggle.

<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: screenshot]

You could also try temporarily changing your language to English to see if the description is any better thay way. Or, of course, you could send yourself a couple e-mails with and without the setting checked and see how the notifications behave.

Comment: My assumption was correct. I changed my phone to English and it said "Notify for every message". Thanks for the help, the translation was a bit confusing.